# multiple spl_autoload_register issue

Tags: php, class, spl-autoload-register

I'm working on the development of a custom framework.
And I have encountered an issue when I tried to dynamise the calling of my classes.

This is a visual of my files :

[image]

So I decided to create a different function for each folder (libs, controllers et modeles):

```
function autoloadLibs($class) {
    //require the general classes
    require 'libs/' . $class . '.php';
}

function autoloadModels($class) {
    //require the models classes
    require 'models/' . $class . '.php';
}

function autoloadControllers($class) {
    //require the controllers classes
    require 'controllers/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register ('autoloadLibs');
spl_autoload_register ('autoloadControllers');  
spl_autoload_register ('autoloadModels');
```

Nevertheless I have this message : **Warning: require(libs/admin.php): failed to open stream**, of cours it's not the good folder. But I don't know how to fix that. Is there a good way to optimise my classes calls ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After few tests, I found this solution for my case :

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(get_include_path(), './libs', './controllers', './models')));
spl_autoload_register();
```

Comment: Could you show how you did it as a whole? Because I am trying to also achieve this but I am not getting any closer :/ Did you put the set_include_path in your functions or just before the functions?

Comment: Aah now I see, you need to delete the function as it includes them automatically! Just copy paste actually XD

Comment: Does this however load all available files in the directories?

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the file exists first with [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) before you attempt to `require` it.

When using `spl_autoload_register()`, I've found it's generally better to register one method to include the files. The fact that you can bing multiple functions I believe is to make interoperability with different libraries easy (so they don't clobber `__autoload()`). It will also save you having to write the code out multiple times to check for the file's existent, map `_` to directory separator (if you do that), etc.

So, assuming you change your filenames to suit the convention of `Underscore_Separated_Name`, e.g. `Controller_Admin_Dashboard`, you could use...

```
function autoload($className) {

    $path = SYSPATH .
            str_replace("_", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($className)) . 
            ".php";

    if (is_file($path)) {
        require $path;
    }

}
```

The first time you instantiate `Controller_Admin_Dashboard`, PHP may include a file such as `/app/controller/admin/dashboard.php`.

Comment: I used the convention of Symfony2 for naming the controller : "BundleName"+"Controller".php
Anyway, I tried to rename all my classes like : Controller_Admin, Controller_Base etc. So I had to rename my folder : "controllers" ==> "controller" etc... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple `spl_autoload_register` calls you need to make sure you don't use the `require` keyword to include the files, because this means **"include the file or die if it can't"**.

Personally I disagree with others about only having one autoload function, especially if you are including classes from different locations, such as a controllers versus some library directory. I also check if the file exists first, *then* include it.

**tl;dr version:** Don't allow `spl_autoload_register` calls to block each other.

Comment: There is just the first spl_autoload_register which is executed so it's normal if the path is wrong.
I don't know how to call each class dynamically

Comment: this solve my issue, but the question is, even after the last autoload function fails to find and include the file, how to throw exception?

Answer (score 3):

your answer is here.
when you are registering multiple autoloaders, php try to load a class by anyone of those autoloaders, **Then**, php calls those autoloaders from the first registered to the last.
    **Then**, in anyone of those autoloaders you should check that file_exists or not, **else**, php try to include it and throws an error if that file does not exist. **Then**, before inclusion, check existance of file.
**Change Your Autoloaders To:**

```
function autoloadLibs($class)
{
  #require the general classes
  $file = 'libs/' . $class . '.php';
  if(file_exists($file))
    require $file;
}

function autoloadModels($class)
{
  #require the models classes
  $file = 'models/' . $class . '.php';
  if(file_exists($file))
    require $file;
}

function autoloadControllers($class)
{
  #require the controllers classes
  $file = 'controllers/' . $class . '.php';
  if(file_exists($file))
    require $file;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check class names before requiring the file, for example:

```
function autoloadControllers($class) {
    //require the controllers classes
    if( substr( $class, -10) == 'Controller')){
        require 'controllers/' . $class . '.php';
    }
}
```

I find it correct to cause error if class cannot be loaded, but you should make sure that `require` is called only on correct path.

Comment: @AdrienG I gave you an example, not whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `spl_autoload_register` provides a third parameter (`prepend`). You can set this to `true` if you wish to place a specific autoload function on top of the autoload stack. This means that this specific function will then be called first.

Example:

> spl_autoload_register(array('My_Class', 'My_Method'), true, true);

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php