# In PHP, when autoloading files, where PHP will look for these files?

Tags: php, require, autoload, include-path

I have an MVC-based application with a basic URL-rewriting rule, which makes the URL look like this: `website/controller/action/id`. The `id` is optional.

If a user enters an invalid `action`, he should get an error which is handled in the class `ErrorController`.

All of my classes files are required in an `autoloader` file, so I should not require them every time I want to create an object. I use `spl_autoload_register()` for autoloading.

The problem occurs when I try to entering a URL with an invalid `action`. For example, for the URL `website/main/inde` (instead of `index`) - an instance of `ErrorController` should be created.

Instead, I get this two PHP errors:

> **Warning**: require(**!core/errorcontroller.php**): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   **D:\Programs\Wamp\www\fanfics\v0.0.2!core\autoloader.php** on line **5**

And

> **Fatal error:** require(): Failed opening required
>   '**!core/errorcontroller.php**' (include_path='**.;C:\php\pear**') in
>   **D:\Programs\Wamp\www\fanfics\v0.0.2!core\autoloader.php** on line **5**

Here is a visual of my files (the exclamation mark before the `core` folder is for keeping it on the top):

[image: visual of my files]

**index.php:**

```
<?php

require "!core/autoloader.php";

$loader = new Loader();
```

**!core/autoloader.php**

```
<?php

function autoload_core_classes($class)
{
    require "!core/" . strtolower($class) . ".php";
}

function autoload_controllers($class)
{
    require "controllers/" . str_replace("controller", "", strtolower($class)) . ".php";
}

function autoload_models($class)
{
    require "models/" . str_replace("model", "", strtolower($class)) . ".php";
}

spl_autoload_register("autoload_core_classes");
spl_autoload_register("autoload_controllers");
spl_autoload_register("autoload_models");
```

**!core/basecontroller.php**

```
<?php

abstract class BaseController
{

    protected $model;
    protected $view;
    private $action;

    public function __construct($action)
    {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->view = new View(get_class($this), $action);
    }

    public function executeAction()
    {
        if (method_exists($this->model, $this->action))
        {
            $this->view->output($this->model->{$this->action}());
        }
        else
        {
            // Here I create an ErrorController object when the action is invalid
            $error = new ErrorController("badmodel");
            $error->executeAction();
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to require `controllers/error.php` specifically - it works just fine:

```
.
.
.
else
{
    require "controllers/error.php"; // With this line it works just fine
    $error = new ErrorController("badmodel");
    $error->executeAction();
}
```

After an online really long search, I understand that there is maybe a problem with the `include_path`, but I do not quite understand it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Point the autoloader to the directory of your classes and it will get them.

Comment: I tried to move it to the root (along with `index.php`). Still the same errors. :(

Comment: Register a single autoloader not 3.

Comment: But why? according to the `php.net` documentation, "If there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register() allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions, and runs through each of them in the order they are defined", and in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939741/1925272), the auothor use the same technic. Also, I tried to putting all in one function with some `if` - same errors.

Comment: @Sipo the error is coming from your core autoloader but you need to autoload a controller. The controller autoloader isn't called since the core autoloader error'd. Use `include` as a sloppy way to get around this. `require` will cause fatal errors if it fails.

Comment: Check that answer again. He registers one not 3. Preferably you should use `file_exists` before actually requiring.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? I am not sure I understand how to do it. Still pretty new to all the autoload idea. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea for each autoloader function to check if the file exists before blindly trying to include/require it. Autoloaders are not expected to throw any errors and should fail silently so they can allow the next autoloader in the queue to attempt to autoload the necessary files.

```
<?php

function autoload_core_classes($class)
{
    if (is_readable("!core/" . strtolower($class) . ".php"))
        include "!core/" . strtolower($class) . ".php";
}

function autoload_controllers($class)
{
    if (is_readable("controllers/" . str_replace("controller", "", strtolower($class)) . ".php"))
        include "controllers/" . str_replace("controller", "", strtolower($class)) . ".php";
}

function autoload_models($class)
{
     if (is_readable( "models/" . str_replace("model", "", strtolower($class)))
        include "models/" . str_replace("model", "", strtolower($class)) . ".php";
}

spl_autoload_register("autoload_core_classes");
spl_autoload_register("autoload_controllers");
spl_autoload_register("autoload_models");
```

Comment: It does solve the errors I mentioned, but now a new error: "**Fatal error: Class 'ErrorController' not found in D:\Programs\Wamp\www\fanfics\v0.0.2\!core\basecontroller.php on line 52**"

Comment: My bad. I'll amend the answer. I copy pasted the first `is_readable` and replaced the path and didn't notice you were doing an `str_replace` for the next files.

Comment: **Fatal error: Class 'MainModel' not found in D:\Programs\Wamp\www\fanfics\v0.0.2\controllers\main.php on line 17**. But I think I figured out a solution based on your answer. If I do, I will edit your answer and accept it. :)

Comment: @Sipo MainModel seems to be needed in the controller which is of a different relative path so `is_readable(__DIR__.`... and `include __DIR__.`... would probably work.

Comment: @apokryfox - you code suddenly works. I did not change anything. I have no Idea why it did not work and now it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP searches for inclusions in paths defined into the property *include_path*. For command line you can check its value with:

```
php -i | grep include_path
```

For web check it with:

```
phpinfo()
```

In any case you can modify the value within php.ini.

I used to *chdir()* in the root of the project in my single entry point and then include files with relative path from root. This is working because *include_path* usually contains the current directory "."

Comment: Can you add an example please?

Comment: I meant: in apache I rewrite every request to a single entry point, say /my/app/path/index.php, and here I add at the very beginning something like *chdir(__ DIR __)*. So that every next inclusion can be made as relative from /my/app/path/